# How to run many PHP scripts parallel and redirect output of each script to a file?

Tags: batch-file

Suppose I have a PHP script which takes two parameters from command line and just prints them as output.

I want a batch file which runs many of these PHP scripts parallel with different parameters and redirect the output of each script to a different file.

I tried something like

```
start "" php index.php 1 2 >> tmp1.txt
start "" php index.php 3 4 >> tmp2.txt
```

It runs them parallel and their outputs are printed into console window. But I want to *redirect* each output *to a file*.

What to modify in batch file to get output of `index.php` redirected to the file?

Comment: There may be a spacing issue. Try putting `>>tmp1.txt` and `>>tmp2.txt` at the beginning of their respective lines instead.

Comment: Nop. it just had the same result.

Comment: `start "" cmd /C ^>^> tmp1.txt php index.php 1 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft article about [using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) explains the differences on using `>` or `>>` or `|`.

What is wrong with following line?

```
start "" php index.php 1 2 >>tmp1.txt
```

This line results in appending output of command **start** to file `tmp1.txt` which is not wanted here.

What is the solution?

The redirection operators are no longer interpreted by command processor for command **start** by escaping the angle brackets with `^`, but for `php.exe` started in a new command process.

```
start "" php.exe index.php 1 2 ^>^>tmp1.txt
start "" php.exe index.php 3 4 ^>^>tmp2.txt
```

The disadvantage of the two lines above is that each console window opened for each new process remains open after `php.exe` finished processing script file `index.php`.

The solution is using the code provided already by [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini) with starting a new command process with option `/C` to close the command process and its console window automatically after `php.exe` terminated.

```
start "" cmd.exe /C php.exe index.php 1 2 ^>^>tmp1.txt
start "" cmd.exe /C php.exe index.php 3 4 ^>^>tmp2.txt
```

The redirection can be also specified left of application which output is redirected and appended to the specified file.

```
start "" cmd.exe /C ^>^>tmp1.txt php.exe index.php 1 2
start "" cmd.exe /C ^>^>tmp2.txt php.exe index.php 3 4
```